# Are canvas.toDataURL compatible with PHP's base64_decode?

Tags: php, javascript, canvas, base64

My problem is as follows...
I have a screen in which the user can select a PNG image from its computer, using this:

```
<input id='icon' type='file' accept='image/png' style='width:400px; height:20px' onchange='llenarThumbnail(this)'>
<img id='thumb' src='#'>
```

When the user selects the image, a thumbnail is shown automatically, using onclick='llenar Thumbnail(this)', like this:

```
function llenarThumbnail(input){
 if (input.files && input.files[0]){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e){
   $('#thumb').attr('src', e.target.result).width(48).height(48);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
 }
}
```

Then, when the user clicks on the proper button to upload the image (not a submit button), I do the following to encode the image into Base64:

```
function getBase64Image(img){
 var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 canvas.width = img.width;
 canvas.height = img.height;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
 console.log(dataURL);
 return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Then, using AJAX I send this encoded image data to the server, and a PHP script does the following:

```
$binary=base64_decode($imagen_data);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen($icono, 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
```

As I was printing diferent alerts along the process, I could see that the encoding was performing (i'm not so sure if correctly or not), and PHP receives the data and creates the PNG file, but when I open the image, the image is empty, there's no data... Thats why I'm asking if this to methods are compatible... I guess they are because they're both Base64... But if its not this, then what am i doing wrong???

Please, I'm tired of looking for this all over the internet! I need some answers! Thank you!

Comment: If you need some other piece of code, just tell me... thank you!

Comment: datauris can use whatever encoding they want. for canvas images being "urled", it probably will be base64, but there's no requirement it actually HAS to be base64. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme  in other words, you should parse the first part of the data url to see if there's an encoding specified in it.

Comment: make a test: comment the last replace `dataURL.replace(...)` and then catch the AJAX request. Copy the dataURL and then paste it in your  browser to see if the image is ok. Then do the same in the PHP side: echo the data URL and paste it in the browser. With this we will see if its a problem of comununication between the client and PHP and its not getting corrupted from that.

Comment: Did you test the data-uri in the browser first (copy the result from toDataURL and paste it in as an url in a new tab) and the image shows correctly?

Comment: I just tested the result of toDataURL in the browser and it shows the image correctly... could be that the problem is this line  dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")?? because i tested the string without those first words and it crashes...

Comment: problem is PHP, afer base64_decode it shows this: "�PNG  IHDR00W��1IDAThCe����F!�ݎ�oT����6���t&��\h@o+]�,q���|m�^��M7���A�C��{V(���u��6,oC�}���|ߧ���L%9� �"

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your ajax POST, here's a *Wild Guess*:

Try leaving the prefix on until the URL gets to php.

Which php server are you using?

Some other usual gotchas:

- Make sure you have properly set up your upload directory.
- Make sure you have permissions set properly on the upload directory.

Client Side:

```
// create a dataUrl from the canvas
var dataURL= canvas.toDataURL();

// post the dataUrl to php
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "upload.php",
  data: {image: dataURL}
}).done(function( respond ) {
  // you will get back the temp file name
  // or "Unable to save this image."
  console.log(respond);
});
```

Server File: upload.php

```
<?php

// make sure the image-data exists and is not empty
// php is particularly sensitive to empty image-data 
if ( isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"]) ) {    

    // get the dataURL
    $dataURL = $_POST["image"];  

    // the dataURL has a prefix (mimetype+datatype) 
    // that we don't want, so strip that prefix off
    $parts = explode(',', $dataURL);  
    $data = $parts[1];  

    // Decode base64 data, resulting in an image
    $data = base64_decode($data);  

    // create a temporary unique file name
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

    // write the file to the upload directory
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    // return the temp file name (success)
    // or return an error message just to frustrate the user (kidding!)
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save this image.';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get markE solution to work, had to change the data modification :

From :

```
$parts = explode(',', $dataURL);  
$data = $parts[1];
$data=base64_decode($data)
```

To :

```
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $dataURL);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data=base64_decode($img);
```

[Method from](https://www.dynamsoft.com/codepool/upload-html-canvas-data-to-php-server.html)